# Query returning only the leaf nodes from SSAS Cube using MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap-cube, mdx-query

I have a requirement to list out the parent levels of the resultant leaf node into their corresponding columns into a single row.

The below query return the expected result

```
  SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Value] } ON COLUMNS, 
    NON EMPTY { ([Account].[Account List].[Account List].ALLMEMBERS ) } 
        DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION ON ROWS FROM [My Cube]
```

This return me result of the format

```
My Child | 1234
```

But what i am looking for the something similar to

```
Parent 5| Parent 4| Parent 3| My Child| 1234
```

Basically i will need the leaf node **ONLY**

So i tried the below query which does return the leaf, but it also include its parents as well which i am not interested in.

```
 SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Value] } ON COLUMNS, 
    NON EMPTY { (DESCENDANTS([Account].[Account].[Level 02].ALLMEMBERS) ) } 
        DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION ON ROWS FROM [My Cube]
```

The above returns the result something of the format

```
> Parent 5| Null| Null| Null| 1
> Parent 5| Parent 4| Null| Null| 12
> Parent 5| Parent 4| Parent 3| Null| 123
> Parent 5| Parent 4| Parent 3|My Child| 1234
```

From the above result i need only the last row. Of course one solution is to write it to a table and filter out the "null rows". But is there a better way to get the leaf only?

Just fyi, our solution is to use SSIS to query the Olap using MDX and extract it out to 2 dimensional table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following `LEAVES` parameter in the `DESCENDANTS` function will do what you want. Documentation for this function is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/descendants-mdx?):

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Value] } ON COLUMNS, 
    NON EMPTY { DESCENDANTS([Account].[Account].[Level 02].ALLMEMBERS, , LEAVES) } 
        DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION ON ROWS FROM [My Cube]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve. If you want to return the value for leafs only, try the following:

```
With 
Member [Measures].[ValueLeaf] as
IIF(IsLeaf([Account].[Accounts].CurrentMember),[Measures].[Value],Null)

Select 
Non Empty [Measures].[ValueLeaf] on 0, 
Non Empty Descendants([Account].[Account].[Level 02].ALLMEMBERS) DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION on 1 
From [My Cube]
```